# Why static_cast enum class that underlying type is int8_t to get an unexpected value?

Tags: c++, static-cast, enum-class

- compiler     : clang++
- c++ standard : c++20

I tried to run the code, and the results met my expectations very well.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum class Num : int
    {
        one = 1,
        two = 2,
        zero = 0
    };

    Num e = Num::one;
    auto a = static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Num>>(e);

    cout << "-----------" << endl;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << "-----------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
-----------
1
-----------
```

But when I made a small modification, changing the underlying type of enum class from int to int8_t,the result was unexpected.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum class Num : int8_t // from 'int' to 'int8_t'
    {
        one = 1,
        two = 2,
        zero = 0
    };

    Num e = Num::one;
    auto a = static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Num>>(e);

    cout << "-----------" << endl;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << "-----------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
-----------

-----------
```

What happened here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int8_t` maps to `char`, and this type is by default printed as its character representation. The character with value 1 is a control character which you can't see.

So, `cout << (int8_t)65` will print `A` and not `65` because the single character `'A'` has value 65.

You can avoid that by casting to `int` before printing: `cout << (int)a`, or alternatively use the unary plus operator: `cout << +a`.